# Number of solutions for equations with complex variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

A question about the number of solutions for the following equation:

$$z^2+(1-i)z-3i=0$$

So the solutions are:
$$z_{1,2}=\frac{-1+i \pm \sqrt{10i} }{2}$$ But $\sqrt{10i}$ has two options with itself: $\sqrt5+\sqrt5i$ and $-\sqrt5-\sqrt5i$, so the equations has 4 solutions?!

Thank you for any answer about this, quite confused.

Comment: there are only two. $z_\pm = \frac{(-1+i) \,\pm\sqrt{5}(1+i)}2$

Comment: No it still has two because the square roots are opposite to each other so $\pm$ becomes $\mp$

Comment: AH right! thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, just $2$ solutions. The $\pm\sqrt{\Delta }$ is to make reference at the two square root of $\sqrt {\Delta }$. Actually, as you can see, if you take the two square root, you will arrive two time twice at the same value (and thus in your 4 solutions, you will have the same solutions two times).

The best is: try and you'll see :-)

Answer (score 0):

use this formula to get the all roots 
$$\frac{1}{2}(1+i)^2=i$$

$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(1+i)^2}=\sqrt{i}$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|1+i|=\sqrt{i}$$

for your question,
$$\sqrt{10i}=\frac{\sqrt{10}}{\sqrt{2}}|1+i|=\sqrt{5}|1+i|$$
$$\sqrt{10i}=\pm \sqrt{5}(1+i)$$

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental theorem of algebra states that a polynomial of degree $n$ has $n$ roots, no less, no more.

If the proposed equation had four distinct roots, you could factor it as $(z-z_0)(z-z_1)(z-z_2)(z-z_3)$, a fourth degree polynomial !

So without even looking at why your conclusion is wrong, you can be sure that it is wrong.